# Moving Bootcamp to new Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

Is it possible to move Boot Camp from Macbook Pro Late 2008 w/ Lion to Macbook Pro 2011 w/ Lion?

I have been trying unsuccessfully for several days.

I used WinClone to successfully image my old Bootcamp, and then ran it on my new Macbook, but it errored just before it finished.

The error was similar to this one:

http://roaringapps.com/app:904#post-2927

The command line commands in that article fixed my first problem of Windows not showing up on reboot despite holding the  key, but now when I boot into it, it just blue screens.

So my question is:  Is this even possible?

Is the hardware difference between the two Macbooks causing the blue screen, and the only solution is to re-install from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is a problem with Windows as opposed to Boot Camp.  Windows, if I remember correctly looks for the serial numbers and unique identifiers when it starts up and has a conniption if they're not what it's expecting.  I ran into this a few years ago when I had the logic board replaced on my iMac.  I think your best bet might be to reinstall Windows on your new machine and migrate your data and settings over within Windows (that might also help Windows by giving a fresh, healthy install).

Comment: I am fine with that - but what is the best way to do that?  What ghosting program works well w/in boot camp?

Comment: Do a normal Windows installation using the Windows CD.  Then import from the old computer.  Note: Windows 7 rescue media does not work well with Boot Camp - it zaps the whole drive including OS X .